# Using Favicon With Bookmarklets

Tags: bookmarklet, favicon

I have a bookmarklet for my webservice. This is bookmarklet link's code :

(spaces added for readability)

```
javascript: void((function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/bookmarklet.js');
    document.body.appendChild(e)
})())
```

And i want to add favicon for this bookmarklet link. I found [this post](http://www.tapper-ware.net/blog/?p=97) about it.

They give an example javascript code for adding favicon

```
javascript:’<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello World</title><link rel=”icon” type=”image/png” href=”http://www.tapper-ware.net/devel/js/JS.Bookmarklets/icons/next.png” /></head><body>Hello World</body></html>’;
```

I want to use this method on my bookmarklet code. I have to combine this codes. But this isn't work.

**readability version** :

```
javascript: void((function () {
    document.write('<html><head><link rel=\'shortcut icon\' href=\'http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/favicon.ico\'/></head></html>');
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/bookmarklet.js');
    document.body.appendChild(e)
})())
```

**Original version :**

```
javascript:void((function(){document.write('<html><head><link%20rel=\'shortcut%20icon\'%20href=\'http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/favicon.ico\'/></head></html>');var%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('src','http://www.girmiyor.co.cc/bookmarklet.js');document.body.appendChild(e)})())
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding his post.

Comment: Opps, why ? His method is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it totally wrong from that example. You don't need to document.write the HTML tags directly. I suggest you to read again the article and understand the branching it does.

I'm sorry if I'm not more specific, but I will just repeat the same that's already on the article you linked.

Comment: so, this is NOT possible ? Can't i add favicon to my bookmark ?

Comment: It IS possible, you just got the article wrong. Read it again and understand it. You missed the very basics of it, the point of the void(0), the window[whatever], how it branches...

Comment: thanks i will read, now. So, how can i add favicon to my bookmarklet ?

Comment: Reading the article, understanding it, and then applying the knowledge you just got to fix your bookmarklet and make it work. I'm not going to write it for you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not work in Chrome, and not well in Firefox.
Up to now, the only way to have an icon for a bookmarklet in Chrome is to generate a bookmark (.HTML) file the user is importing where the bookmark has an icon attached.
This is very painful, but all other tentatives fails somehow.

For chrome, generate a file that contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1346919281" LAST_MODIFIED="1381755311" PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER="true">Favorite</H3>
        <DL><p><DT><A HREF="javascript:(your bookmarklet here *MUST BE THE SAME AS THE BOOKMARKLET CODE*)" ICON="data:image/png;base64,your base64 encoded icon here">Your bookmarklet name here *MUST BE THE SAME AS THE BOOKMARKLET*</A>
        <DT>
    </DL><p>
</DL><p>
```

Then let the user save this file as mybookmark.html and then let it import it in the "Favorite manager" (open favorite manager, then right click on the root folder, select 'Import HTML bookmark...'). This is completely safe as the import goes into a new folder, and it can be deleted immediately after import.

Chrome recognizes it's the same URL (the javascript code) and title, and reuse the icon.